# How Do I Add A checkBalance Function To This ERC20 Smart Contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I Need To Know The Balance Of This Token After I Deploy It In Remix Ethereum Firefox. I Want To Know Where Do I Add The checkBalance Function. Plz Help Guys. This Is My First ERC20 Smart Contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract TusharCoin {

  uint256 public totalSupply;  
  string public name;  
  string public symbol;  
  uint32 public decimals;
  address public owner;

  mapping(address => uint256 ) balances;

  event Transfer(address to, uint256 amount);

  constructor () public {
    symbol  = "TUSHAR";  
    name = "TusharCoin";  
    decimals = 5;  
    totalSupply = 100000000000;
    owner = msg.sender;  
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, totalSupply);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your token currently isn't an ERC20 token as it doesn't fully implement the ERC20 standard yet.

To just add a `balanceOf` function to your existing contract you can add the following:

```
    function balanceOf(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[account];
    }
```

If you are creating your own ERC20 implementation then you should consider using SafeMath, see the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/utilities#math

If you are creating ERC20 tokens you may want to look at the OpenZeppelin Contracts implementation to see if this meets your needs. See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens#ERC20

An example ERC20 Token that you can deploy with Remix inheriting from the OpenZeppelin Contracts implementation is below using your specified name, symbol, decimals and totalSupply:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.3.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.3.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

contract Token is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {

    constructor () public ERC20Detailed("Tushar Token", "TUSHAR", 5) {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals())));
    }
}
```

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin

Answer (score 0):

Below, I have mention checkBalance function. In ERC20 standards checkBalance function to be stated as a  balanceOf function. 
In function, view means one can only read not write

```
function balanceOf(address accountAddress) public view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[accountAddress];
}
```

Full source code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract TusharCoin {

  uint256 public totalSupply;  
  string public name;  
  string public symbol;  
  uint32 public decimals;
  address public owner;

  mapping(address => uint256 ) balances;

  event Transfer(address to, uint256 amount);

  constructor () public {
    symbol  = "TUSHAR";  
    name = "TusharCoin";  
    decimals = 5;  
    totalSupply = 100000000000;
    owner = msg.sender;  
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, totalSupply);
    }

    function balanceOf(address accountAddress) public view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[accountAddress];
    }
 }
```

If you want whole code for ERC20. Let me know.